# TextView and Button textColor disappear

Tags: android, button, textview, textcolor

I'm having an issue with a TextView and three Buttons that are part of a Fragment. The text color will occasionally disappear(every 5th or 6th time fragment is created, approximately). The text and background remain fine. It is only the textColor that I'm having an issue with. This is a game using libgdx run from one Fragment. The menus and such are run from separate Frag.

[Link to pics](http://rustyrobotgames.uphero.com/images.html)

Here is xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_quit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="MENU"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/btn_quit"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="PLAY"
            android:textColor="#ffed0d0d"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_quit"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:textColor="@color/meep_red"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/btn_play"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is Java.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diescreen_fragment, container,
                false);

        /* Determine whether the Activity requested to show ads */
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        boolean showAd = false;
        int score = 0;
        if(args != null){
            showAd = args.containsKey(ARG_SHOW_AD) ? args.getBoolean(ARG_SHOW_AD) : false;
            score = args.containsKey(SCORE) ? args.getInt(SCORE) : 0;
        }

        /* Initialize advertisements */
        mBanner = new RevMobBannerAd(getActivity());
        mFullscreen = new RevMobFullscreenAd(getActivity());
        mFullscreen.setFullscreenAdListener(new FullscreenAdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDisplay() {
                canClick = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                canClick = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdDismissed() {
                canClick = true;
            }
        });

        /* Show FullscreenAd if requested */
        if(showAd && net.hasConnection()){
            canClick = false;
            mFullscreen.showAd();
        }

        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/PLUMP.TTF");

        playSound = GamePrefsHelper.isSoundOn(getActivity());
        bannerView = (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.banner);
        mBanner.showAd(bannerView);
        sound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.btn_sound);
        scoreView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scoreText_dieScreen);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));

        (playBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_play)).setOnTouchListener(this);
        (quitBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_quit)).setOnTouchListener(this);
        (scoreBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_score)).setOnTouchListener(this);
        playBtn.setTypeface(font);
        quitBtn.setTypeface(font);
        scoreBtn.setTypeface(font);
        view.requestLayout();

        return view;
    }
```

The @color/red is my custom red which is shown in btn_play. I have tried using both hard coded color and pulling from a resource file, with no success. I have tried stripping the Buttons and TextView down to bare minimum- no color, standard background and no font- and then adding in transparent background, font and color. Background, text, font and functionality are always fine. Text color is the only thing that disappears.

This was also added at the end in my futile attempt to fix the symptoms.

```
   view.requestLayout();
```

Log output

```
09-27 02:49:23.102: D/OpenGLRenderer(29488): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
09-27 02:49:23.102: E/OpenGLRenderer(29488):   GL_INVALID_VALUE
09-27 02:49:23.805: D/[RevMob](29488): Fullscreen static for orientations
09-27 02:49:23.805: D/libc(29488): Forward DNS query to netd(h=creatives.revmob.com s=^)
09-27 02:49:24.992: I/[RevMob](29488): Banner loaded - 527a5678b8f9d1984b00014b
09-27 02:49:25.070: D/dalvikvm(29488): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 615K, 12% free 17229K/19491K, paused 70ms, total 70ms
09-27 02:49:25.086: I/dalvikvm-heap(29488): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.669MB for 2908176-byte allocation
09-27 02:49:25.141: D/dalvikvm(29488): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 11% free 20007K/22371K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
09-27 02:49:25.172: D/OpenGLRenderer(29488): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
09-27 02:49:25.172: E/OpenGLRenderer(29488):   GL_INVALID_VALUE
09-27 02:49:25.922: I/Choreographer(29488): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-27 02:49:26.492: D/libc(29488): Forward DNS query to netd(h=creatives.revmob.com s=^)
09-27 02:49:26.719: D/dalvikvm(29488): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 357K, 11% free 20104K/22371K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
09-27 02:49:26.727: I/dalvikvm-heap(29488): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.477MB for 2908176-byte allocation
09-27 02:49:26.781: D/dalvikvm(29488): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 10% free 22905K/25251K, paused 58ms, total 58ms
09-27 02:49:27.375: D/libc(29488): Forward DNS query to netd(h=android.revmob.com s=^)
09-27 02:49:27.406: I/[RevMob](29488): Fullscreen loaded - 527a5678b8f9d1984b00014b
09-27 02:49:31.047: D/OpenGLRenderer(29488): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x501
09-27 02:49:31.047: E/OpenGLRenderer(29488):   GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

I have searched through many many many posts on stackoverflow as well as studied the Android Developer site to better understand the issue. No luck!

Please help stackoverflow! You're my only hope! ;)

Comment: try and remove the frameLayout.. and tell me will that fix the issue

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski thanks for suggestion. i've just tried and, unfortunately, it didn't fix the issue.